# Как правильно вставить картинку в html текст?

Tags: java, android

Имеется текст в html, в папке assets.
В Этот текст нужно вставить картинку (png). Вот как я делаю:

```
....На спомин Господа Бога і Спаса нашого Ісуса Христа <font COLOR='RED'>(тричі).</font><br />

<p style="text-align: center;">
<img src='" + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.proskomydiya_1)"'/>
</p><br />

І надрізує копієм з правого боку печатки (з лівої руки священика)...
```

В DetailsActivity прописываю код:

```
 Html.ImageGetter imageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {

        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {

            Drawable d;
            if(string_title.contains("lit_1_part_2" ) || string_title.contains("lit_2_part_2")){
                d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.proskomydiya_1);
            } else {
                d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.proskomydiya_2);
            }

            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, d.getIntrinsicHeight()/2);
            return d;

Но картинка получается то слишком большая, то слишком маленькая.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно привязать ширину и высоту картинки к размеру экрана?
Я попробовал вот так, но ничего хорошего не получилось.

```
 int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
 int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            d.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            return d;
```

Comment: <img src='" + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.proskomydiya_1)"' width="200" height="200">

Comment: К сожалению так тоже не работает.

Comment: Странно. Я встраивал свои размеры в тэг `<img src` и у меня все работало

Comment: Вот и я не пойму, что не так я делаю. А что вы в активити пишите, может мне там нужно код подправить? Потому что, какие бы числа я не прописывал в <img src приложение ни как не реагирует.